# Field has incomplete type even though included

Tags: c, include, header-files

One of my headers files `queue.h` has a structure with has a structure defined in another file, `pathing.h`. `queue.h` includes `pathing.h`, but not vice versa. The compiler, gcc, is telling me that the structure is an incomplete type. Multiple files in the project include both of them, but I made sure they include `pathing.h` first. I have look at various post with the same problem, but they seemed to be caused by forward declaration or circular inclusion. As far as I can tell, mine isn't.

##### queue.h

```
#include "pathing.h"
typedef struct _queue{
    struct queue* below;
    struct point_t value;
}queue;

point_t pop(queue* a);
point_t peek(queue a);
void add(queue* a, point_t pointer);
```

##### pathing.h

```
#ifndef _pathing_
#define _pathing_
typedef unsigned char byte_t;
typedef struct _point_t{
    int x;
    int y;
}point_t;

int exec(int argc,char* arg[]);
#endif
```

Comment: What is the name of the structure, `_queue` or `queue`?

Comment: Remove the `struct` in front of `struct point_t value` in your `queue` struct.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg That is a format I picked up from reading other peoples code. I reference it as queue and that seems to work. I really don't know why the people I am working with put the _name before it.

Comment: @ckruczek Thanks, that worked.

Comment: I'm not talking about the leading underscore, I'm talking about the name mismatch, you define a structure named `_queue` but uses `queue` inside the structure. Possibly confusing it with the `queue` type-alias you define *later*.

Comment: Names ending with `_t` are reserved for POSIX headers. And there's no point in mismatching the tag name vs typedef name - just use `typedef struct point point; struct point {...};` (this will also make the typedef usable within the body)

Comment: In addition to above, you are missing an #include guard in your queue.h file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
typedef struct _queue{
    // This is a typo. You are missing the _ before queue.
    // struct queue* below;
    struct _queue* below; 
    struct point_t value;
}queue;
```

Regarding `point_t`, there is no such thing as `struct point_t` in your code. You can use:

```
struct _point_t value;
```

or

```
point_t value;
```

Comment: @yesennes If you post a question about build errors, please always include the actual, complete and unedited error output in the question. That makes it so much easier to see what the error actually is.